# can't get permission to post on facebook read_stream

Tags: php, facebook

I need permission to post facebook status via application

and can't get access to read_stream

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
"scope" => "read_stream,publish_stream"));
 header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
```

Do I have to submit to review ?
sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

The only way to **NOT** send the review, it's if the selected permissions are on admin (of your Facebook app) users.
For example, if you want to create an app which post new status when you create a topic on your forum, you'll access to your own "manage_pages,publish_stream" permissions, and you are the administrator of your app, so the review is not require.

But, when you want to access to your website users permissions, you need to send a review. It takes ~2 business days.

Comment: I need to post new status to many users not only me so I have to submit review ?

Comment: "publish_stream" permission is for publish something on the wall, so it's ok : you have to submit a review.